# Duplicating a value from a string to other strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

d = {
    'oper_dt' : [dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19)]
    , 'oper_dttm' : [dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,43,43), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,43,50), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,43,57), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,44,9)]
    , 'user_id' : [111111, 111111, 111111, 111111]
    , 'status_process' : ['Start', None, 'Success', None]
    , 'status_type' : [None, None, 'ready', 'print']
    , 'sprvk_type' : [None, '2NDFL', None, None]
}

d1 = {
    'oper_dt' : [dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19)]
    , 'oper_dttm' : [dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,47,47), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,48,50), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,49,5)]
    , 'user_id' : [111111, 111111, 111111]
    , 'status_process' : ['Start', None, 'Success']
    , 'status_type' : [None, None, 'ready']
    , 'sprvk_type' : [None, 'TAX_DEDUCTION', None]
}

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d), pd.DataFrame(d1)])
```

I want to duplicate the values from the column "sprvk_type" to the rows depending on the values in the column "status_process". "Start" as value in column "status_process" is the beginning of a new process.
Finally, I need DataFrame like this

```
d = {
    'oper_dt' : [dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19)]
    , 'oper_dttm' : [dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,43,43), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,43,50), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,43,57), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,44,9)]
    , 'user_id' : [111111, 111111, 111111, 111111]
    , 'status_process' : ['Start', None, 'Success', None]
    , 'status_type' : [None, None, 'ready', 'print']
    , 'sprvk_type' : ['2NDFL', '2NDFL', '2NDFL', '2NDFL']
}

d1 = {
    'oper_dt' : [dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19), dt.date(2024,1,19)]
    , 'oper_dttm' : [dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,47,47), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,48,50), dt.datetime(2024,1,19,9,49,5)]
    , 'user_id' : [111111, 111111, 111111]
    , 'status_process' : ['Start', None, 'Success']
    , 'status_type' : [None, None, 'ready']
    , 'sprvk_type' : ['TAX_DEDUCTION', 'TAX_DEDUCTION', 'TAX_DEDUCTION']
}

pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(d), pd.DataFrame(d1)])
```

Comment: You can certainly replace all of the NA values in that column with the first non-NA value before you do the concatenation.  Wouldn't that work?

Comment: Aside: Don't use `dict` as a variable name, you're overwiting the built-in type.